# How to switch to frame having given HTML using Selenium

Tags: selenium

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<header class="masthead">
<div id="mydiv">
<object id="frame" data="tdreporthome.html"></object>
</div>
<footer class="navbar default-footer">
</body>
</html>
```

In the above html structure if I want to switch Selenium control to  frame how to do so using Selenium ?

Comment: The following link may help you http://aksahu.blogspot.in/2015/05/dealing-with-object-tags-in-selenium-webdriver.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

```
//Object[@id='frame']
```

you can use the above xpath